# How to access an double pointer type argument as 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays

Something like this:

```
struct s
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

void f(struct s **a)
{
    a[0][0].a = 0; // Access violation here
}

int main()
{
    struct s a[5][3];
    f(a);
    return(0);
}
```

So how can I access content of a inside function f using 2D array notation?

Comment: why don't you use something else than `a`?

Comment: A pointer is not an array and an array is not a pointer!

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have to type code (and format them) on the phone so I tried to make it simple. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array like `a[5][3]` stores the `struct` instances contigously, while `struct s **a` will store pointers contigously such that each pointer points to one instance of `struct s`. So `struct s a[5][3]` (*which is automaticaly converted to a pointer*) and `struct s **a` are incompatible pointers, if you compile with warnings you would know that.

A simple solution would be

```
void f(struct s a[][3])
{
    a[0][0].a = 0; // Access violation here
}
```

A better solution, is

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct some_structure
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
};

void
set_value(struct some_structure **array, size_t row, size_t column)
{
    array[row][column].value1 = 0;
    array[row][column].value2 = 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct some_structure **array;
    array = malloc(5 * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL)
        return -1; // Allocation Failure
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof(*(array[i])));
        if (array[i] == NULL)
            return -1; // Allocation Failure
    }
    set_value(array, 0, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

As you see when I say above *will store pointers* it is because you need to allocate memory for that, you can by using `malloc()` like the example above.